# Applying css by clicking link

Tags: html, css

[This website](http://jgthms.com/web-design-in-4-minutes) doesn't seem to be using any javascript (besides something for webfont). Yet clicking a link applies a set of css rules. How does it work and what feature(s) of html/css is being used here?

As far as I can tell, `data-step` attribute seems to be playing some part in this. But I'm not familiar with how this works to produce the desired affects.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Web Design in 4 minutes</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="website.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header id="header">
      <img id="logo" src="jt.png" alt="JT logo">
      <h1>Web Design in 4 minutes</h1>
      <p>
        <a href="http://jgthms.com" target="_blank">by Jeremy Thomas</a>
      </p>
    </header>

    <main>
      <section id="start">
        <p>Let's say you have a product, a portfolio, or just an idea you want to share with everyone on your <em>own</em> website. Before you publish it on the internet, you want to make it look attractive, professional, or at least <em>decent</em> to look at.</p>
        <p>What is the <a class="step" data-step="0" href="#content">first thing</a> you need to work on?</p>
      </section>

      <section id="content">
        <h2>Content</h2>
        <p>The purpose of <strong>design</strong> is to enhance the presentation of the content it's applied to. It might sound obvious, but content being the <strong>primary</strong> element of a website, it should not be established as an afterthought.</p>
        <p>Written content, like the paragraph you're currently reading, makes up for more than 90% of the Web. Styling this textual content will go a long way.</p>
        <p>Let's assume you've already finalised the content you want to publish and just created an empty <code>style.css</code> file, what is the <a class="step" data-step="1" href="#centering">first rule</a> you can write?</p>
      </section>

      <section id="centering">
        <h2>Centering</h2>
        <p>Long lines of text can be hard to parse, and thus hard to <strong>read</strong>. Setting a limit of characters per line greatly enhances the readability and appeal of a wall of text.</p>
<pre><span class="selector">body</span> {
  <span class="attribute">margin</span>: <span class="number">0</span> auto;
  <span class="attribute">max-width</span>: <span class="number">50</span><span class="unit">em</span>;
}</pre>
        <p>After styling the text <em>blocks</em>, what about styling the <a class="step" data-step="2" href="#font-family">text itself</a>?</p>
      </section>

      <section id="font-family">
        <h2>Font family</h2>
        <p>The browser's font defaults to <code>"Times"</code>, which can look unappealing (mostly because it is the "unstyled" font). Switching to a <strong>sans-serif</strong> font like <code>"Helvetica"</code> or <code>"Arial"</code> can vastly improve the look of your page.</p>
<pre><span class="selector">body</span> {
  <span class="attribute">font-family</span>: <span class="string">"Helvetica"</span>, <span class="string">"Arial"</span>, sans-serif;
}</pre>
        <p><em>If you want to stick with a serif font, try <code>"Georgia"</code>.</em></p>
        <p>While this makes the text more <em>appealing</em>, let's also make it <a class="step" data-step="3" href="#spacing">more readable</a>.</p>
      </section>
      ...
```

**CSS**

```
/* Base styles */

a strong {
  color: inherit;
}

hr {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d8dee9;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

pre {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

footer {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 4em;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Initial state */

#visited {
  background-color: white;
  bottom: 0;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#visited:visited {
  background-color: #e81c4f;
}

#logo,
section,
footer {
  display: none;
}

#start {
  display: block;
}

/* 00 Content */

html.step0 #content {
  display: block;
}

/* 01 Centering */

html.step1 #centering {
  display: block;
}

html.step1 header,
html.step1 main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 50em;
}
...
```

Comment: I have updated the question since posting. The repo code is different and running a local copy of the html file from the repo doesn't have the same affect. It shows the final page. The website has the relevant code and the affect I'm interested in.

Comment: You did see that chunk of JavaScript at the end of the body right?

Comment: it uses javascript to assign classes:`if (target !== '') {
    var id = target.split('#')[1];
    document.getElementById(id).className = 'animate';
  }`

Comment: @j08691 I see it now. I was originally looking at the repo code and didn't look too deeply at the website. I'll delete this question. It is not relevant. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

The website is working on `href` and `id` concept. (same page navigation)

http://jgthms.com/web-design-in-4-minutes/

Example:

```
<a href="#id">go to id</a>
<div style="margin-top:2000px;"></div>
<a id="id">id</a>
```

This refers to same page navigation. By default the content is `display:none` and on click of it, it is visible.

Hope it helps you.

Cheers!